# Using replaceRoot in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have my collection like this :

```
{
   {
      "productType":"Bike",
      "company":"yamaha",
      "model":"y1"
   },
   {
      "productType":"Bike",
      "company":"bajaj",
      "model":"b1"
   },
   {
      "productType":"Bike",
      "company":"yamaha",
      "model":"y1"
   },
   {
      "productType":"Car",
      "company":"Maruti",
      "model":"m1"
   },
   {
      "productType":"Bike",
      "company":"yamaha",
      "model":"y2"
   },
   {
      "productType":"Car",
      "company":"Suzuki",
      "model":"s1"
   }
}
```

I want this data :

```
  [ "Bike":{
      "Yamaha":{
         "y1":2,
         "y2":1
      },
      "Bajaj":{
         "b1":1
      }
   },
   "Car":{
      "Maruti":{
         "m1":1
      },
      "Suzuki":{
         "s1":1
      }
   
]
```

I tried to use `$replaceRoot` but could not do it with that (Key should be the `productType` then `company` then the `model` with `count` of that model as the value). How to do this ? In which case specifically we should use $replaceRoot ?

Edit : since the whole answer was inside a json object, I removed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `$group` by `productType`, `company`, and `model`, and count the total
- `$group` by `productType` and `company`, construct array using `model` and `count` of models in key-value format
- `$group` by `productType`, construct array of company using `company` and `model` object that is converted from array using `$arrayToObject`
- `$group` by null, construct array of `product` using `product` and `company` object that is converted from array using `$arrayToObject`
- `$replaceRoot` to replace converted `product` array to object using `$arrayToObject`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        productType: "$productType",
        company: "$company",
        model: "$model"
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        productType: "$_id.productType",
        company: "$_id.company"
      },
      model: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.model",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.productType",
      company: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.company",
          v: { $arrayToObject: "$model" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      product: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: { $arrayToObject: "$company" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$product" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8__hXTjL2hf)

Comment: I am just getting one extra parent (or the key) in which whole answer is surrounded as the value. That key is named "products".

Comment: can you confirm this https://mongoplayground.net/p/8__hXTjL2hf

Comment: aggregate() always return in array, so you can use direct zero element from response.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION #1**: Result as separate documents.

```js
db.products.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                company: "$company",
                model: "$model"
            },
            productType: { $first: "$productType" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.company",
            productType: { $first: "$productType" },
            v: {
                $push: {
                    k: "$_id.model",
                    v: "$count"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$productType",
            k: { $first: "$productType" },
            v: {
                $push: {
                    k: "$_id",
                    v: { $arrayToObject: "$v" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceWith: {
            array: [
                {
                    k: "$k",
                    v: { $arrayToObject: "$v" }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$array" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output: Result as separate documents.

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "Bike" : {
        "yamaha" : {
            "y1" : 2,
            "y2" : 1
        },
        "bajaj" : {
            "b1" : 1
        }
    }
},

/* 2 */
{
    "Car" : {
        "Maruti" : {
            "m1" : 1
        },
        "Suzuki" : {
            "s1" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION #2**: Result as single document.

```js
db.products.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                company: "$company",
                model: "$model"
            },
            productType: { $first: "$productType" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.company",
            productType: { $first: "$productType" },
            v: {
                $push: {
                    k: "$_id.model",
                    v: "$count"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$productType",
            k: { $first: "$productType" },
            v: {
                $push: {
                    k: "$_id",
                    v: { $arrayToObject: "$v" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            array: {
                $push: {
                    k: "$k",
                    v: { $arrayToObject: "$v" }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$array" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output: Result as single document.

```js
{
    "Bike" : {
        "bajaj" : {
            "b1" : 1
        },
        "yamaha" : {
            "y1" : 2,
            "y2" : 1
        }
    },
    "Car" : {
        "Maruti" : {
            "m1" : 1
        },
        "Suzuki" : {
            "s1" : 1
        }
    }
}
```